# why is the template being rendered before the service calls are resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the Resolve feature in the ui router in my SPA on some other states but for some reason on my server dashboard state it is calling the template before the service calls have finished rendering. This is causing a type error since I am trying to use the values that are being passed before they have been resolved.

Here is my StateProvider:

```
.state('triangular.server-details', {
    url: '/dashboards/Server/{hostName}',
    templateUrl: 'app/examples/dashboards/server/dashboard-server.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'DashboardServerController as serverDetails',
    resolve:{
        ServiceList:['$stateParams','ServerService', function($stateParams, ServerService){
            return ServerService.getServices($stateParams.hostName);
        }],
        HostData:['$stateParams','ServerService', function($stateParams, ServerService){
            return ServerService.getHost($stateParams.hostName);
        }]
    }
})
```

Here is the getHost function in the service.js:

```
service.getHost = function(HostName){
    var HostList = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost:9000/Host/' + HostName).then(function(response){
            var Data = response.data.recordset;
            for (i = 0; i <= Data.length -1; i++){          
                HostList.push({
                    "HostName" :Data[i].HostName,
                    "address" :Data[i].Address,
                    "alias":Data[i].Alias,
                    "nagios":Data[i].Nagios,
                    "hoststatus":Data[i].Status,
                    "hoststatuscheck" : Data[i].LastCheck,
                    "hosticon" : Data[i].ShortStatus,
                })
            }
        })
    return HostList;
};
```

Here is My Controller:

```
DashboardServerController.$inject = ['ServiceList', 'HostData', '$scope'];
function DashboardServerController(ServiceList, HostData, $scope) {
    var serverDetails = this;
    serverDetails.ServiceList = ServiceList;
    serverDetails.HostData = HostData;
    console.log(serverDetails.HostData);
    console.log(serverDetails.HostData[0].HostName);
}
```

When I first go to the page it prints the HostData in the console but a type error occurs when trying to print the HostName. then after that the api calls to get the servicelist and Hostdata are made. if I refresh the page I get NO errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getHost method needs to return a promise if you want the resolve to wait.
Refactor to something like this:

```
service.getHost = function(HostName){
var HostList = [];
return $http.get('http://localhost:9000/Host/' + HostName).then(function(response){
        var Data = response.data.recordset;
        for (i = 0; i <= Data.length -1; i++){          
            HostList.push({
                "HostName" :Data[i].HostName,
                "address" :Data[i].Address,
                "alias":Data[i].Alias,
                "nagios":Data[i].Nagios,
                "hoststatus":Data[i].Status,
                "hoststatuscheck" : Data[i].LastCheck,
                "hosticon" : Data[i].ShortStatus,
            })
    return HostList;
        }
    })
```

};

Comment: Thank YOU!! I will always remember to use promises in these situations.